# Is there a complete list of facet names?

Tags: visualforce

Does there exist a comprehensive list of the apex:facet names for different objects, or at least a way to retrieve them? I'm starting to build visualforce pages for our org, but not knowing what I can reference where is a bit restrictive.
I've seen the example at the bottom of the [Visualforce Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) page for apex:datatable, and found reference to others such as name=start and name=stop, but nothing complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a list available, on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230309/ffacet-there-is-a-list-of-predefined-names-attributes) found the following answer:

> You cannot find a predefined names list for facets. because facets are
>   relatiad to components. Every components supports different facets.
>   e.g. h:datatable supports header and footer. primefaces datatable
>   supports header, footer and emptyMessage facets. best way to find
>   supportted facets you should look source code of component renderers.
>   [Primefaces DatatableRenderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java), [Mojarra TableRenderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.4/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/TableRenderer.java)

Another explanation on this [forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/214246/JSF/java/facet-funtionality) states:

> the name part of facet can be anything. For example if you are writing
>   a tree component, when you instantiate each Node, you pass in a
>   string. For a node name, like if you were writing a tree component to
>   represent a file system, you would have 2 different kinds of nodes,
>   namely, directory, and file. So to show each Node differently you use
>   the facet tag.
>
> Have a look at some tree examples if this doesn't make sense,
>   hopefully the examples do.